# javascript- ReferenceError: require is not defined

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack

I'm trying to bundle and run a TypeScript project using Webpack.
One of the TypeScript files requires and external node depenedency.
Webpack bundles the file without problem, but when I try to run it on the browser it gives me the following error.

[image: Error message]

**webpack.config.js**

```
const path = require('path');
const nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.ts',
  resolve: {
    extensions: [
      '.js',
      '.jsx',
      '.json',
      '.ts',
      '.tsx'
    ]
  },
   externals: [nodeExternals()],
  output: {
    libraryTarget: 'commonjs',
    path: path.join(__dirname, '.webpack'),
    filename: '[name].js',
  },
  target: 'web',
  module: {
    loaders: [
      { test: /\.ts(x?)$/, loader: 'ts-loader' },
    ],
  },

};
```

**External node dependency**
[aws-iot-device-sdk](https://github.com/aws/aws-iot-device-sdk-js)

Can someone help me with this?

Update: Found that the following line in the TypeScript file causes the issue.
is there a work-around for this?

```
const client = new IoTClient(true, IoTClientOptions);
```

Comment: Why are you setting output.libraryTarget to 'commonjs', have you tried to   set it to `libraryTarget: "umd"`?

Comment: I have no clear idea about the libraryTarget option and I tried with the option you mentioned, but the error remains the same.

Comment: What's inside `./src/index.ts`?

Comment: The following line: const client = new IoTClient(true, IoTClientOptions);

Comment: Can you provide more content in `index.ts`, I have no idea what IoTClient and IoTClientOptions are.

Comment: I was able to find a solution, I will add here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following Webpack configuration solved my issue.

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    chatUI: './src/chat-ui.ts',
    chatLogic: './src/chat-logic.ts',
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: [
      '.js',
      '.jsx',
      '.json',
      '.ts',
      '.tsx'
    ]
  },
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, '.webpack'),
    filename: '[name].js',
  },
  node: {
    fs: 'empty',
    tls: 'empty'
  },
  target: 'web',
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        loader: 'awesome-typescript-loader'
      }
    ],
  },

};
```

Answer (score 1):

As you are using

```
require('path');
```

you have to download RequireJS

[Here](http://requirejs.org/docs/download.html)

RequireJS is a JavaScript file and module loader.

or add Add http://requirejs.org/docs/release/2.2.0/minified/require.js to your project